# Win32 API : Mutex hangs even though it's released

Tags: windows, winapi, process, mutex

I'm trying to set up inter-process communication via a mutex. I have one process which does this:

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, "amutex_name");
if (!hMutex) {
    puts("Error creating mutex. Aborting.");
    return;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
    if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED) {
        puts("Error waiting for mutex. Aborting.");
        return;
    }
    if (!ReleaseMutex(hMutex)) {
        puts("Error releasing mutex. Aborting.");
        return;
    }
    puts("MUTEX RELEASED");
    Sleep(2000);
}
CloseHandle(hMutex);
```

And a second program (different process) which does this:

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "amutex_name");
if (!hMutex) {
    puts("Error creating mutex. Aborting.");
    return;
}
while (1) {
    if (WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED)
        continue;
    if (!ReleaseMutex(hMutex)) {
        puts("Error releasing mutex. Aborting.");
        return;
    }
    puts("GOT ONE");
}
CloseHandle(hMutex);
```

The first program outputs a lot of `MUTEX RELEASED` as expected, but the second program doesn't output anything. Why is that?... after releasing the mutex from the first program, the second one should have enough time (2000 ms; even if I set it to higher I get the same result) to claim ownership of the mutex through the `WaitForSingleObject` function. What am I missing? I've been punching myself in the head for the last couple of hours.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
  HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, "amutex_name");
```

The TRUE argument does not do what you hope it does.  A mutex is *re-entrant*, a thread is allowed to acquire it more than once. It internally counts the number of times it has been entered by the owner thread, an equal number of ReleaseMutex() calls are required to release the mutex.

So the first program acquires it immediately with the bInitialOwner = TRUE argument. Then the WFSO call acquires it *again*, the internal counter will be 2. The ReleaseMutex call can only lower the counter back to 1, not good enough to release it.  So the 2nd program can never acquire it as long as the loop is running.

It gets worse after the CloseHandle() call, the OS now marks the mutex as *abandoned*.  A bad state, it knows that the original thread can never get the internal counter back to 0.  That makes the WFSO call in the second program fail permanently with WAIT_ABANDONED.  You probably did not wait for ~20 minutes to get into that state.

Get ahead by passing FALSE.  And by improving the error handling, if you don't get WAIT_OBJECT_0 back from the WFSO call then Something Really Bad Happened and your only recourse is to terminate the program.